# Criar um repositória remoto através da linha de comando

Tags: git

Existe essa possibilidade, em um servidor como o GitHub por exemplo? Se sim, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Olá, comece dando uma olhada em conteúdos como [este](https://pt.wikiversity.org/wiki/Criando_seu_proprio_servidor_de_git), não é algo simples vai te exigir muito estudo e dedicação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando a API do Github

O primeiro passo seria criar um access token. Para fazer isso, você pode seguir as instruções desta página:

https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line

Com o access token, você pode criar um novo repositório usando Curl. Um exemplo:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token ACCESS_TOKEN" --data '{"name":"NEW_REPO_NAME"}' https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

Aqui tem um link do StackOverflow com outros exemplos:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385884/how-to-create-repository-in-github-through-github-api

E o link da documentação:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create